# Intellij generate static final fields

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

in a project I need to create many fields with the same type and access modifier 

is there a way in intellij to generate public static final fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type all names on separate lines, select the lines and do a regex replace for the selection.

```
(\w+)

public static final XYZ $1 = new XYZ("$1");
```

Being comfortable with regex in editing belongs to a developer's basic tools.

By the way **interfaces** do not need `public static final`; that is implicit.

Answer (score 2):

If you type `psf` and then hit tab, intelliJ will type `public static final` for you. unsure if this is what you are after

Comment: thank, that help, but I wonder If there's a way to specify the names of fields , the type (since they have the same) and boom, the fields are generated

Comment: @aName I suppose the only thing i could think of, as i don't believe there's a tool built in to do so, is to write out your first one, then press CTRL+D to duplicate the line as many times as you need, then rename each one to your desired names.

Comment: Additionally, if you enter `prsf` you'll get a `private static final`

Comment: @QBrute yep, a lot of useful shortcuts for defining method and variable types in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

When you go for *Generate* (for example using command-N on MacOs), IntelliJ only suggests to generate all kinds of methods for you.

I am not aware of a method to insert (almost) identical variable declarations into one (or multiple) java source files.

My workaround: when I have to declare multiple (almost) identical things, I simply turn to [column](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206711965-How-do-I-toggle-column-selection-mode-on-a-Mac-See-image-) mode.

In other words: I "column" select 5 or 10 empty rows, and then start typing. When the common part is there, I disable column mode and do the necessary fixes for each line manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize Intellij's `File and Code templates`. Those are used every time a Java class or another entity is created through a project's context menu. Here is the screenshot with a custom template created.

[image: A context menu with a custom template]

To make your own choose `Edit File Templates...` option. You can copy the structure of any template and populate it with your own fields. Syntax is quite transparent—guides can be found [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-file-and-code-templates.html).

Here is an example of a custom template which creates a class with a certain amount of fields of type String and prefix of your choice.

[image: A screenshot of template creation]

Upon a file creation you will be asked to specify a class and a variable name.

[image: Input dialog]

After this a file with the following code will be created in no time.

```
public class MyClass {

  public static final String myString1 = "";
  public static final String myString2 = "";
  public static final String myString3 = "";
  public static final String myString4 = "";
  public static final String myString5 = "";
  public static final String myString6 = "";
  public static final String myString7 = "";
  public static final String myString8 = "";
  public static final String myString9 = "";
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that once created, templates can be reused instantly. Besides, they can describe rather complex file structures and will save you a lot of time if you create typical files frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this which I use a lot is [multiple cursor](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/multicursor.html) feature. First, you paste the field names, such that each one is on a separate line, left-aligned. Then `Alt`+select the left border of the names. Then type or paste `public static final String`  or whatever you need, it appears on every line. Then press `End` to move all the cursors to the end of the lines and type  `= "";`, and that's it.

You can also use this for more complex editing, like adding annotations to the fields or bulk setting field values.